# UIImagePickerController is very slow to load a video file

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

It's really slow to load video file from photo library of my iPhone by using `UIImagePickerController`. It took about 30s to load a 580mb video file.

The code is simple:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
imagePicker.delegate = self
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The delegate callback which is called after very long time after I pick the video file in photo library.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. In order to provide you with an actual video, the runtime must *export* the video from the library. This can take a long time, as the entire video must be re-rendered. The longer the video the longer the export time. The callback must not come until the export is complete; hence the delay.

You might get some speed up by setting the `videoQuality` to a lower quality.

Note that there is no delay at all with PHPickerViewController because it takes a completely different approach: it calls the delegate method immediately with an item provider, and no video is provided unless you explicitly ask the item provider to do so (which can take some time). See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontroller.